# IAsyncResult AsyncState property is always null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

I have a library that contains both synchronous and asynchronous implementations of a function, that connects to some hardware and reads some data. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class Reader
{
    private HardwareService service = new HardwareService();
    private string[] id = new string[128];

    public string[] ReadData()
    {
        // Synchronous implementation that works, but blocks the main thread.
        return service.ReadID();
    }

    public void ReadDataAsync()
    {
        // Asynchronous call, that does not block the main thread, but the data returned in the callback are always null.
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(ProcessData);
        service.BeginReadID(callback, id);
    }

    static void ProcessData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string[] id_read = (string[])result.AsyncState;  // Always NULL
    }
}
```

Why is it that when I use the non blocking asynchronous call, I always receive array filled with NULL objects? This is the first time I'm using this approach, so I'm a little lost here. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the asynchronous implementations, the user state is retrieved as it is set during starting the asynchronous operation. Since you pass a string[] with all null values, you get it back.

You are not invoking EndReadID() of the service to get the results.

Try the following: (I am assuming that the service implements the EndReadID method, and it should, if it follows the standard practices)

```
static void ProcessData(IAsyncResult result)
{
    string[] id_read = service.EndReadID(result);
}
```

Comment: Great, that works, thanks! I just don't know why I have to pass an object instance to the BeginReadID function whan I'm reading a new instance of an object with the result by calling the EndReadID.

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček The user state is very useful to pass objects to the callback methods. The callback methods can execute in any thread and can be static etc, thus disconnected from the context started the operation. You don't have to put anything into the state because 1. you don't need anything but the service instance, and 2. your callback function is an instance member of your class and can access other members of it (eg: service instance)

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Just pass null in these cases.